# Is it okay to add "onchange" event directly to the html code?

Tags: javascript, html

I read that adding styles or javascript  such as "onclick" to html is bad practice. I wonder same would apply to "onchange" events?

```
<select name ="backdrop" onchange="buttonChanger(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

The [drawbacks of `onclick` attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice) apply to all `on*` attributes.